# Inequality in "PRIMES is in P"

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I'm having trouble verifying an inequality that is claimed in "PRIMES is in P" (Annals of Mathematics, 160 (2004), 781-793).

I'll state it in such a way that it can be understood without the paper, but for the curious it is in the middle of the proof of Lemma 4.3.

Assume that $n$ is an integer satisfying $n \geq 3$.  Then it is claimed that
$$n \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor \log^2 n \rfloor} (n^i-1) < n^{\log^4 n}.$$
Here the log functions means the base-$2$ logarithm.

It is easy to verify a somewhat weaker inequality.  Namely, each term in the product is at most $n^{\log^2 n}-1$, so we have
$$n \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor \log^2 n \rfloor} (n^i-1) \leq n \cdot (n^{\log^2 n}-1)^{\log^2 n} < n \cdot (n^{\log^2 n})^{\log^2 n} = n^{\log^4 n +1}.$$
However, try as I might I cannot seem to get rid of the $1$ in the exponent.

Comment: The product on the left is $\lt\prod_{i=1}^{\log^2 n} n^i = n^{\sum_{i=1}^{\log^2 n} i}$. But the latter is roughly $n^{(\log^4 n)/2}$ by the usual triangular sum, and the exact claim presumably comes from some quick  massaging of the exact constant terms.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Oh, you're totally right.  I feel like an idiot for not noticing that.  Thanks!